# Should one use const when declaring an arrow function in React class

Tags: reactjs, constants, arrow-functions

Inside a react class component, should one use a const/let to declare an arrow function, or they should be emmited:

```
  class ReactComp extend Component {
      const sayHello = () => {
          return 'Hello';
      }
      sayBye = () => {
          return 'Hello';
      }
      render() {
          <div>
            {this.sayHello}
            {this.sayBye}
          </div>
      }
  }
```

In this example, is sayBye declared correctly? (Without a const)

In addition, why outside the class, such a declaration does not work?

```
  class ReactComp extend Component {

      render() {
          <div>
            {sayHello}
            {sayBye}
          </div>
      }
  }
  const sayHello = () => {
      return 'Hello';
  }
  sayBye = () => {
      return 'Hello';
  }
```

This will return an exception: Uncaught ReferenceError: sayBye is not defined

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Run the code yourself and see which one works. Incorrect will throw SyntaxError.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is "it depends"... your two examples do very different things. Let's take a look at both before I give you a more detailed answer.

```
class ReactComp extend Component {
  const sayHello = () => {
      return 'Hello';
  }
  sayBye = () => {
      return 'Hello';
  }
  render() {
      <div>
        {this.sayHello}
        {this.sayBye}
      </div>
  }
}
```

The code above probably throws a syntax error as `const` (in this context) is not a valid decorator. Even if it was valid (or you simply omit it), `sayHello()` becomes a method on the `ReactComp` class (i.e. an instance method). Every time you create a new instance of this component, it will have an internal method called `sayHello`.

```
const example = <ReactComp />;
example.sayHello(); // oversimplified example
```

Make sense? On to your next example:

```
class ReactComp extend Component {
    render() {
        <div>
          {sayHello}
          {sayBye}
        </div>
    }
}
const sayHello = () => {
    return 'Hello';
}
sayBye = () => {
    return 'Hello';
}
```

Ignoring for a moment the syntax error you mentioned earlier, this code creates two global(ish) functions: `sayHello()` and `sayBye()` which (depending on your other code) could be accessed globally by any other component or script.

```
sayHello(); // I can run this line of code anywhere!
// no need for "const example = <ReactComp /> because sayHello() was defined outside of that class
```

*My point:* instance methods on a class are different than functions declared outside of a component.

**Should one use `const` when declaring an arrow function in React class?**

If you're creating an instance method, then *no* you don't need `const`. If you're creating a generic (i.e. utility) function outside of a component, then *yes* you probably should use `const`.

Comment: Very helpful, I also had the same doubt.

Answer (score 3):

You can't define a variable using any declarative statement inside a class.

It expects property names to be attached to the **this** context of your class.

Defining the following class:

```
class C extends Component {
 sayGoodBye = () => console.log("Bye!")
 sayHello = who => console.log("Hello " + who)

 render() {
   this.sayGoodBye()
   this.sayHello('world')
   // ...
 }
}
```

can be translated as:

```
const C = {
  sayGoodBye : () => console.log('bye!'),
  sayHello : who => console.log('Hello ' + who),
  render : () => {
    C.sayGoodBye()
    C.sayHello('world')
  } 
}
```

if you try to define a variable inside a class using *const/let/var* it will result in an error.